# How WPA actually works?

Tags: security, networking

Can anyone suggest me some source to study WPA security in wireless. On google search all I get are different ways to crack WPA.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First result on google goes to Wikipedia on WPA, which guides you to the actual WPA/WPA standard [IEEE 802.11i-2004](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_802.11i-2004). When googling `802.11i` you get many very good links to presentations, documents and papers about WPA.